# RCurl including xml

Tags: linux, r, curl, rcurl

I have a curl command in linux that works

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic ENCODED_USERNAME_PASSWORD_HERE" -H "Content-Type: application/xml" --data @basicRequest.xml http://abcd/efg/requests/
```

I tried to write the R equivalent for this and this is what I did so far

```
getURL("http://abcd/efg/requests/", login = "m12345", password = "123456", httpauth = 1L)
```

Need help with the rest, no clue how to include the XML file (i have a separate XML file), Content-Type, --data @basicRequest.xml etc...

==================update=======================================

When I run this version of the code

```
 setwd("H:/.../.../TestProject") 
 xmlfile=xmlParse("test1.xml")

 library(httr) ; 
 t2 = POST(content_type_xml(), authenticate("m12345", "123456", type = "basic"), url='http://abcd/efg/requests/', body=upload_file("test1.xml"),verbose())
```

I get the following message

```
-> POST /efg/requests/ HTTP/1.1
-> Authorization: Basic YlRF.....Q==
-> User-Agent: curl/7.39.0 Rcurl/1.95.4.5 httr/0.6.1
-> Host: ....:8786
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/xml
-> Content-Length: 1234
-> Expect: 100-continue
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
>> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
>>  <request>
>>    <api-id>............</input-file>
>>  </request>

<- HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
<- Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
<- Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
<- Content-Length: 951
<- Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 05:28:42 GMT
```

Dont know where I am wrong ?

Comment: try `library(httr) ; POST(content_type_xml(), authenticate("m12345", "123456", type = "basic"), url='http://abcd/efg/requests/', body=upload_file("basicRequest.xml"))`

Comment: @hrbrmstr I get a 400 message. It was appearing very ugly when i try to post the code here so posted the code that I tried based on your suggestion under the updates....not sure what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: you're posting an XML but using `content_type_json`? add a `, verbose()` parameter to `POST` to see if that provides more info.

Comment: @hrbrmstr apologize for that , I changed the code back to content_type_xml() and added verbose() i get a 401 unauthorized message. How do I pass a base64 encoded userid and psswd, i want to test the code by passing base64 encoded login information  to see if it works ?